# How can I link a combobox to a folder of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

In the body of HTML I have `<input type="file" id="img" multiple><br>
 <input type="submit" onclick="loadfiles()">`

In Javascript I have:

```
function loadfiles() {
  var viewer = new PhotoViewer();
  var imageFiles = document.getElementById("img"),
  filesLength = imageFiles.files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
    viewer.add('./Slide1/'+imageFiles.files[i].name);
  }
  viewer.show(0);
```

Here, what I am doing is selecting multiple files from the specific folder and those files are showing in the jQuery slider. But I want to do it as a combobox of folders: whichever folder I choose, it will show all the images present in that folder using the same jQuery slider.

```
<form name=myform>
  <select id="mytextarea" name=mytextarea size=1>
    <option name=one value=one> one </option>
    <option name=two value=two> two </option>
    <option name=three value=three > three </option>
    <option name=four value=four> four </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

How can I can get a link to the folder?

Comment: I dont get a couple things.
1: what is PhotoViewer() that you are referring above?
2: I dont think you can show the Client files to the client without saving them somewhere. What folder are you talking about in the question?

Comment: photoviwer is jquery framewrok through which i can show images in the browser .  Suppose if i choose option 'one' then it will show all the images present in the folder name One, two or three whichever folder user will select.

Comment: you can not show the files that are selected at client through your input type file. Secondly, if you want to show all the images inside a folder at your server, I am afraid you will have to hardcode the images paths for each image.

Comment: You can load any image from your server by url (`var i=document.createElement('image'); i.src=myUrl;`), and you can also show images that are put in the file input as well. For an example of how it's done, check out [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). It only works in modern browsers, however. Old browsers allow no access to such things at all. Btw, to get the current selection, I think $('#mytextarea').val() works. Note that calling it `mytextarea` when it's really a `<select>` may not be the smartest thing to do. It seems you are quite confused about too many things to make it work.

Comment: What does the rest of your stack look like?  Since you can't read the filesystem from html (except Chrome + HTML5), it seems like you really need to build an Ajax endpoint that will give you a list of files based on the directory, which you could then use to populate the photo viewer as you change directories.  Do you have PHP access on this page/site?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass reference of combo Box to function

`<input type="file" id="img" multiple><br>
 <input type="submit" onclick="loadfiles(this)">`

```
function loadfiles(obj) {
  var selectedOption = obj.val();
  }
```